# Combine the "limitslider" and "jQuery-ui-Slider-Pips" jQuery UI extensions

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider-pips

I want to combine [Limitslider](https://github.com/vanderlee/limitslider) and [jQuery-ui-Slider-Pips](https://github.com/simeydotme/jQuery-ui-Slider-Pips), two extensions to the [jQuery UI slider widget](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/), into a single slider.

Unfortunately, both extensions take a different approach to extending the base library. jQuery-ui-Slider-Pips uses `$.extend()` to add additional methods to `$.ui.slider.prototype`, while Limitslider defines a new jQuery UI widget and re-uses parts of the original slider. This makes it difficult to combine the two.

I tried several ways to make it work, but they all failed so far...

---

*1st attempt, "I wonder if this works"*

```
$('#slider').limitslider().slider('pips');
```

This one understandably didn't work because there is no 'pips' function in the limitslider prototype.

---

*2nd attempt, "I should be able to do this, right?"*

```
var extensionMethods = {
  pips: $.ui.slider.prototype.pips,
  float: $.ui.slider.prototype.float
};
$.extend(true, $.vanderlee.limitslider.prototype, extensionMethods);
$('#slider').limitslider().limitslider('pips');
```

Extending Limitslider with the methods provided by jQuery-ui-Slider-Pips doesn't help, because those methods internally use the original 'slider()' method and "slider" namespace. (I even tried refactoring the jQuery-ui-Slider-Pips code, changing "slider" references to "limitslider", but I couldn't make it work.)

---

*3rd attempt, "Why didn't I think of this before?"*

```
var extensionMethods = {
  pips: $.ui.slider.prototype.pips,
  float: $.ui.slider.prototype.float
};
$.widget('ui.slider', $.extend({}, $.vanderlee.limitslider.prototype, extensionMethods));
$('#slider').slider().slider('pips');
```

Redefining the original ui.slider as the merge-result of the jQuery-ui-Slider-Pips and Limitslider seemed like a such good idea. Unfortunately it only returns errors (Chrome: "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded", Firefox: "too much recursion"). I guess it triggers an infinite loop.

---

**Question**: What is the way, if any, to make these two extensions work together?

Answer (score 1):

I am not convinced these two are going to work nicely together, however I have taken a quick look and it's clear to see you're on the right track!

The Limit Slider is an `instanceof $.ui.slider` meaning it should inherit the prototype chain (including `pips/floats`). After inspecting the data of a **limit slider instance** I can confirm that to be true.

You can access the instance of a slider by using `$(".myslider").data()`.

The code you'll need (and is semi-working) is:

```
var $slider = $(".myslider").limitslider({
    min: 0,
    max: 30,
    gap: 2,
    values: [10, 15]
});

var sliderInstance = $slider.data().vanderleeLimitslider;
sliderInstance.pips();
sliderInstance.float();
```

**https://jsfiddle.net/64n6u20q/1**
**`^^^ Working Fiddle.`**

**Caveat**; This is only working visually for Pips, and I'm not sure it will continue to work with more complicated settings from **Limit Slider**. You'll have to experiment.

**More Caveats**; I can see a bunch of errors due to handling of events. This should be due to **Limit Slider** not implementing the same event interface, or it's deleting that event. Either way I'd suggest you figure out a way to disable those events (`$.off()` should be enough).

Comment: Thanks for looking into this! I will continue my attempts to get the details working. I did notice a problem in your fiddle though... The float doesn't update its value when you slide the handle. The console shows "originalMousedown is not a function". It looks like the problems I ran into in my 2nd attempt.

Comment: Follow up: I ended up not combining the two extensions, I kept running into errors one way or the other. I'm now using jQuery-ui-Slider-Pips and implemented some Limitslider-ish features with custom code (eg. http://stackoverflow.com/a/44102147/241546).